# At the other edge beyond Newton with General Relativity? #2

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, galaxy-rotation-curve, post-newtonian

The Schwarzschild solution is derived by using the static, spherically symmetric solution
$$ds^2=-B(r)dt^2 + A(r) dr^2 +\text{angular terms},$$

assuming a concentrated mass, therefore gaining $A=1/B$ from $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ outside the mass

and (more importantly) from assuming $\lim A(r) = 1$ for asymptotical flatness.

My question is, would it be possible to derive a stronger gravitational law than Newton from the assumption that $\lim A(r) = 0$? Does this work or is it somehow in conflict with the original field equations? Has it been calculated out anywhere in a paper before?

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Newtonian_expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Birkhoff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)), the only spherically symmetric solution of the vacuum Einstein Field Equations must be the Schwarzschild solution. More precisely,

> Any C^0, piecewise C^1, solution of the Einstein's empty space equations which is spherically symmetric in an open set $V$, is locally equivalent to part of the maximally extended Schwarzschild solution in $V$.

I took the formal statement from [Hawking & Ellis](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/large-scale-structure-of-spacetime/1E6B961EC9878EDDBBD6AC0AF031CC93), Appendix B (they prove for a $C^2$ metric, but mention and provide references to the stronger result).

In essence, if you want to impose the conditions

1. Spacetime is spherically symmetric
2. The stress-energy tensor vanishes on the solution of interest (for example, for $r \to + \infty$)

you automatically imposed that the metric must be the Schwarzschild metric, unless you are considering a theory of gravity different from General Relativity. Hence, you can't impose $\lim_{r \to + \infty} A(r) = 0$, that won't be a solution to Einstein's Field Equations. In other words, $\lim_{r \to + \infty} A(r) = 1$ is not an assumption, but rather a consequence.

Hence, one can't obtain a stronger Newtonian limit through the prescription you have given. It would need to contradict the Einstein Field Equations.

Comment: 1. The lim should be r-> infinity, not r->0 in your equations, right? 2. These are good points. But there is *one* assumption of Birkhoff's theorem and Hawkings statement which you did not mention: They assume the existence of energies only equal or greater than zero, energies below zero they do not allow.

Comment: @BarrierRemoval 1. Indeed, thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected it. 2. I don't think I understand what you mean. Birkhoff's Theorem assumes vacuum which, under the Einstein Equations, means $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$. One assumes, just as you did, that the Ricci tensor vanishes identically, so in this sense no energy at all (positive or negative) is allowed. However, this is also in your assumptions, unless we are not considering a vacuum spacetime (in which case, $R_{\mu\nu} \neq 0$ and Schwarzschild does not apply)

Comment: I should add that I mean vacuum in the classical, general relativistic sense. I.e., vacuum means $T_{\mu\nu} = 0$ and $\Lambda = 0$. I am *not* talking about the vacuum of quantum field theory, that would be an entirely different situation (which does not seem to fit the context of your question, since you explicitly stated the assumption $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$, which is equivalent to the notion of vacuum I'm employing if the assume the Einstein Equations)

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I signed the question as answered. Thank you for pointing this out. Vacuum in Birkhoff's Theorem is truely T= 0. Therefore, it assumes that the energy of the vacuum is true zero.